# Last item animated while removing another in cursor based recycler view

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a Cursor inside. I remove items after swipe (in ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback) - delete from database, change cursor and then call notifyItemRemoved. It works fine, but when all items are on the screen, 
[the last one is animating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deMi3.gif)
My code:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    ...
    viewHolder.getAdapter().removeFromDb(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    viewHolder.getAdapter().removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

}
```

and inside my adapter:

```
 public void removeItem(int adapterPosition) {

    notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
}

public void removeFromDb(int adapterPosition) {
    DBHelper db = ...
    cursor.moveToPosition(adapterPosition);
    db.openDB();
    db.removeItem(...);
    changeCursor(db.newCursor...);

    db.closeDB();

}


public void changeCursor(Cursor _new) {
    cursor.close();
    cursor = _new;
}
```

I saw many other questions, and the easiest solution is to set whole data into ArrayList, but I don't think it's the best idea. In my opinion something is wrong with reloading data to cursor, but I have no idea how to solve it.

 
 **SOLVED**: You have to add

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

in your activity.